# the difference between `\\s|*` and `\\s|[*]` in regular expression in r?

Tags: regex, r

What is the difference between `\\s|*` and `\\s|[*]` in regular expression in r?

```
> gsub('\\s|*','','Aug 2013*')
[1] "Aug2013*"
> gsub('\\s|[*]','','Aug 2013*')
[1] "Aug2013"
```

What is the function of `[  ]` here?

Comment: `*` is a special character in regex, so the `[]` forces a literal interpretation of the character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first expression is invalid in the way you are using it, hence `*` is a special character. If you want to use `sub` or `gsub` this way with special characters, you can use `fixed = TRUE` parameter set.

This takes the string representing the pattern being search for as it is and **ignores** any special characters.

See [`Pattern Matching and Replacement`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) in the [`R`](http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html) documentation.

```
x <- 'Aug 2013****'
gsub('*', '', x, fixed=TRUE)
#[1] "Aug 2013"
```

Your second expression is just using a character class `[]` for `*` to avoid escaping, the same as..

```
x <- 'Aug 2013*'
gsub('\\s|\\*', '', x)
#[1] "Aug2013"
```

As far as the explanation of your first expression: `\\s|*`

```
\s      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
|       OR
```

And the second expression: `\\s|[*]`

```
\s      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
|       OR
[*]     any character of: '*'
```

Answer (score 3):

The use of `[]` here is nothing else but to escape the `*` to a literal asterisk.

The first regex is invalid (`*` is special character meaning "zero or more").

The second regex is equivalent to

```
'\\s|\\*'
```